# Debugging Asp .Net MVC application slow on Windows 10 and IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, typescript, internet-explorer-11, windows-10

One of my Asp .Net MVC applications (VS 2013) are running really slow while debugging on Windows 10 with Internet Explorer 11.0.10240. When I debug the same project on a Windows 7 machine (IE 11.0.9600) with the same settings for VS 2013 everything runs fine.

I ran IE's built in performance profiler on both machines and compared. On the Windows 10 machine the "HTML Parsing -> Script evaluation" for most of my typescript scripts take slightly above 500ms each while they only take a few ms on the Windows 7 machine.

What could cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose speed issues on here I'm afraid :(.  I have Windows 10 and VS2013 and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by NOD32 Antivirus. One of the first things I tried was to "Pause protection" but apparently that didn't turn everything off. In case this happens to anyone else here's what you should do. Go to protocol filtering settings "Setup->Advanced setup->Web and Email". Click "Excluded applications" and select "DEVENV.EXE".